# Firefox input placeholder padding issue

Tags: css, html, firefox, cross-browser, placeholder

Why Firefox not taking padding for Placeholder text. **see example here http://jsfiddle.net/JfrfZ/**

**How to fix it?**

**HTML**

```
<form method="get" action="/search" id="search">
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
</form>
```

CSS

```
#search input[type="text"] {
           background: url(../img/search-icon.png) no-repeat 2.6% 50% #fcfcfc;
               background-size: 6%;
               border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
               font: normal 1.7em Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
               color: #bebebe;
               width: 33%;
               padding: 0.6% 2%;
               border-radius: 3em;
               text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
               box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
               padding-left: 3.8%;
                outline: 0; }
```

Comment: Since you are using percentages as padding - this can be related to: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=527459 ;)

Comment: Percent padding doesn't appear to work in Firefox for `input`s. Absolute values (px, for example) work fine.

Comment: @madflow - I given padding in `em` but still not working

Comment: padding: 2em 2em 2em 2em; - looks fine to me (FF9)

Comment: @madflow - But I want to give relative value

Comment: @madflow - I solved the issue with `em`

Answer (score 8):

You’ll need to use [the `::-moz-placeholder` psuedo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-placeholder) (formerly [`:moz-placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-placeholder)).

```css
 #search input::-moz-placeholder {
     padding: <top> <right> <bottom> <left>;
 }
```

---

There used to be [a bug in Firefox that prevented padding from working on text inputs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=527459). So `text-indent` was the way to go if you needed to use percentages.

```css
#search input:-moz-placeholder {
    text-indent: 3.8%;     
}
```

But the bug was fixed on 2012-08-28 and included in Firefox 17. There is no longer a need to use `text-indent`.

Answer (score 5):

you can use `text-indent`

```css
#search input[type="text"] {
    background: url(../img/search-icon.png) no-repeat 2.6% 50% #fcfcfc;
    background-size: 6%;
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    font: normal 1.7em Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    color: #bebebe;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 0.6% 2%;
    border-radius: 3em;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    padding-left: 3.8%;
    outline: 0; 
    text-indent: 3.8%
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="/search" id="search">
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
</form>
```

Comment: the link didn't work or the solution didn't work? Because for me both work.. Anyways you can just put the `text-indent: 10%` in your CSS and see what happens :)

Comment: Solution didn't work. in my firefox still has no space from left. Firefox require more indent.

Comment: I've checked in FF 8-9 on Windows and FF 10 beta on Mac - all work. What's your FF version?

Comment: It takes the cursor at the edge of input box which i don't want

Comment: Text indent works. It is the easiest solution to move placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change `padding-left` to:

```
text-indent:3.8%;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need add `padding: 0.6% 2%;` into `input { }`